# Holes In Donut Icing Material

Tags: materials

The icing on my donut has small holes around the edges. I didn’t notice exactly when they appeared, but it wasn’t until just recently. I was likely messing with render settings when it happened. Any help is appreciated!

[image: Donut render]

Comment: The dough's displaced geometry is poking through the icing's geometry ;)

Comment: Increase the icing solidify modifier slightly, or decrease the displacement scale

Answer (score 1):

The donut's displacement was poking through the icing. The solution is to either decrease the *Displacement Scale* or increase the icing's *Solidify* modifier *Thickness*.